# Gvim with Ubuntu 10.10 transparency

Tags: gvim, ubuntu-10.10, transparency

Looking to see if its possible or otherwise.

I also have `transparency=15`

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.gvimrc: 
line   25: 
E518: Unknown option: transparency=15
```

So far have gotten that.

Comment: There is no `transparency` setting in vim nor in gvim. The window manager can do that however.